# Why is it not recommended to use webpack mini-css-extract-plugin in development?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

From the `webpack` `mini-css-extract-plugin` documentation it is recommended that:

> This plugin should be used only on production builds without
>   `style-loader` in the loaders chain, especially if you want to have `HMR`
>   in `development`.

Why not use it for both `development` and `production` builds instead of `style-loader` altogether? In some ways I could see that `style-loader` is easier to debug?

Comment: less overhead and faster builds.

Comment: that quote answers the question, are you familiar with HMR? style-loader injects the styles inline as a <style> tag and is much faster, extracting has to process all entry points that contain css and combine them into a css file

Comment: what does the quoted statement mean? If we are only using it for production builds, then what does it have to do with HMR in development ?